# Issue: Google Maps AdvancedMarkerView from Array of Images

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-advanced-marker-element

i'm trying to generate Google Maps Markers from image atributes from an array.

with the former version of the maps Api it worked fine.
i now tried to make it work with the new version (AdvancedMarkerView)

console says
Uncaught ReferenceError: AdvancedMarkerView is not defined /
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: AdvancedMarkerView is not a constructor

any help is greatly appreciated

```js
"use strict";

var active_img = 0;
var stage_img;
var img_lat;
var img_lng;
var parsedLat;
var parsedLng;
var autoplayInterval;
var isautoplay = true;
var firstautoplay = 0;
var autoplaylock = 0;
var mouse_onplay = false;
var map_active = false;
var main_visible = false;
var main_v_lock = false;
var myLatLng = {
  lat: 0,
  lng: 0
};

const images = [{
    path: 'img/img_3.webp',
    img_lat: '41,47873',
    img_lng: '11,99995',
  },
  {
    path: 'img/img_2.webp',
    img_lat: '49,47873',
    img_lng: '10,99995',
  },
];


let map;

async function initMap() {
  var position = myLatLng;
  const {
    Map
  } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const {
    AdvancedMarkerView
  } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");


  map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    mapId: "559497c6e95d32fc",
    zoom: 18,
    center: myLatLng,
    fullscreenControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false
  });

  createMarkers(images, map, AdvancedMarkerView);
}

function createMarkers(images, map, AdvancedMarkerView) {
  const markers = [];

  images.forEach((image, index) => {
    const {
      img_lat,
      img_lng,
      path
    } = image;
    if (img_lat !== '0' && img_lng !== '0') {
      const latLng = {
        lat: parseFloat(img_lat.replace(',', '.')),
        lng: parseFloat(img_lng.replace(',', '.'))
      };

      const marker = new AdvancedMarkerView({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        title: path
      });

      marker.addListener('click', () => {
        handleMarkerClick(index);
      });

      markers.push(marker);
    }
  });

  return markers;
}

initMap();


function ifLost() {
  if (img_lat === '0' && img_lng === '0') {

    img_lng = 'data lost';
    img_lat = '';
  }
}


function img_update() {
  document.getElementById('stage_img').src = stage_img;
  ifLost();
  document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = `<div>${img_lat}</div>`;
  document.getElementById('lng').innerHTML = `<div>${img_lng}</div>`;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  stage_img = images[0].path;
  img_lat = images[0].img_lat;
  img_lng = images[0].img_lng;

  parsedLat = parseFloat(img_lat.replace(',', '.'));
  parsedLng = parseFloat(img_lng.replace(',', '.'));

  myLatLng = {
    lat: parsedLat,
    lng: parsedLng
  };

  if (map) {
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(parsedLat, parsedLng));
  }

  function coordinates_update_move() {
    img_lat = images[active_img].img_lat;
    img_lng = images[active_img].img_lng;

    parsedLat = parseFloat(img_lat.replace(',', '.'));
    parsedLng = parseFloat(img_lng.replace(',', '.'));

    if (map) {

      if (img_lat == '0') {} else {
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(parsedLat, parsedLng));
      }

    }
    ifLost();
  }


  function handleMarkerClick(index) {

    active_img = index;

    stage_img = images[active_img].path;
    img_lat = images[active_img].img_lat;
    img_lng = images[active_img].img_lng;

    img_update();
    coordinates_update_move();

    setTimeout(close_btn2, 440);

  }
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#map_stage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#map {
  height: 50%;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>drau3en</title>

  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>

  <script>
    (g => {
      var h, a, k, p = "The Google Maps JavaScript API",
        c = "google",
        l = "importLibrary",
        q = "__ib__",
        m = document,
        b = window;
      b = b[c] || (b[c] = {});
      var d = b.maps || (b.maps = {}),
        r = new Set,
        e = new URLSearchParams,
        u = () => h || (h = new Promise(async(f, n) => {
          await (a = m.createElement("script"));
          e.set("libraries", [...r] + "");
          for (k in g) e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g, t => "_" + t[0].toLowerCase()), g[k]);
          e.set("callback", c + ".maps." + q);
          a.src = `https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?` + e;
          d[q] = f;
          a.onerror = () => h = n(Error(p + " could not load."));
          a.nonce = m.querySelector("script[nonce]") ? .nonce || "";
          m.head.append(a)
        }));
      d[l] ? console.warn(p + " only loads once. Ignoring:", g) : d[l] = (f, ...n) => r.add(f) && u().then(() => d[l](f, ...n))
    })({
      key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk",
      v: "weekly",
    });
  </script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

  <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="map_stage">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <p id="lat"></p>
    <p id="lng"></p>
  </div>

  <footer>
  </footer>

  <script>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue. This includes your HTML/CSS, how you are loading the API, how your different code snippets are put together and how the functions are called. Most likely, you are calling `createMarkers` before the API has finished loading.

Comment: hi thanks for pointing that out,
i added additional info, such as HTML Head and CSS of map container and map.

is there anything else missing in order to reproduce the issue?

thanks a lot

Comment: Why are you calling `createMarkers` at 2 different places?

Comment: possibly related: [Rename Google Maps Advanced Marker View tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424797/rename-google-maps-advanced-marker-view-tag)

Comment: @MrUpsidown thank you, good point, i removed the second call.

unfortunately now i get 

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: AdvancedMarkerView is not a constructor`

i feel like im missing something really basic

thank you for helping me up to this point, really appreciate it

Comment: Again, please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue. Edit your question and use the code snippet feature (Ctrl+M) to create a runnable code snippet with all the necessary code. You can replace your API key with `AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk` which is a test key for use here on Stack overflow.

Comment: Hi, 
i now modified the post and reduced the code to only the important components.

In the code snippet tool, i can't run it. But locally it produces the error i was referring to.

sorry for being unprofessional, i'm trying my hardest :s

Comment: I can see that you're still using `AdvancedMarkerView` wherein the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/advanced-markers) says that you should use `AdvancedMarkerElement`. Can you try using that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been noted, you need to use `AdvancedMarkerElement` rather than `AdvancedMarkerView`. With that changed you should find it fairly straightforward to add your own custom designed markers to the map at whatever locations you wish using HTML for the marker content.
Perhaps the following, modified code, might help.

The `gmp-click` event which is used below is currently available within the `beta` channel but this does help simplify accessing content within the AdvancedMarkerElement - using the older `click` event is still possible but the clickhandler code would need to be modified to accommodate the change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            :root{--accent:blue}
            body { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; overflow:hidden; padding:0; margin:0; display:flex; flex-direction:column;  }
            body, body *{ box-sizing:border-box; font-family:monospace }
            *:focus { outline: none; }
            
            .advmarker{ background:white; padding:0.5rem; border-radius:1rem; border:1px solid var(--accent); display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; flex-direction:column }
            .map-icon{ width:50px; height:50px; border-radius:50%; border:2px solid black; }
            .advmarker h3{color:var(--accent)}
            
            #map_stage{ width:100%; height:100%; margin:0 auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column; justify-content:flex-start; align-items:center; }
            #map_stage p:before,
            .advmarker span:before{ content:attr( data-id )':'; color:var(--accent) }
            
            #map { height:65%;width:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div id='map_stage'>
          <div id='map'></div>
          <p data-id='lat' id='lat'></p>
          <p data-id='lng' id='lng'></p>
          <img id='stage_img' />
        </div>
        <footer></footer>
        
        
        <script>
        
            const APIKEY='AIza.....';
        
            (g => {
              var h, a, k, p = "The Google Maps JavaScript API",
                c = "google",
                l = "importLibrary",
                q = "__ib__",
                m = document,
                b = window;
              b = b[c] || (b[c] = {});
              var d = b.maps || (b.maps = {}),
                r = new Set,
                e = new URLSearchParams,
                u = () => h || (h = new Promise(async(f, n) => {
                  await (a = m.createElement("script"));
                  e.set("libraries", [...r] + "");
                  for (k in g) e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g, t => "_" + t[0].toLowerCase()), g[k]);
                  e.set("callback", c + ".maps." + q);
                  a.src = `https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?` + e;
                  d[q] = f;
                  m.head.append(a)
                }));
                
              d[l] ? console.warn(p + " only loads once. Ignoring:", g) : d[l] = (f, ...n) => r.add(f) && u().then(() => d[l](f, ...n))
            })({
              key:APIKEY,
              v:'beta'
            });
            
            // above is slightly modified
            

            const myLatLng = {// central europe - ish
              'lat':46.553469,
              'lng':11.761824
            };
            const images = [
                {
                    path: '//placekitten.com/200/200?image=1',
                    img_lat: 41.47873,
                    img_lng: 11.99995
                },
                {
                    path: '//placekitten.com/200/200?image=2',
                    img_lat: 49.47873,
                    img_lng: 10.99995
                },
                {
                    path: '//placekitten.com/200/200?image=3',
                    img_lat: 47.013545,
                    img_lng: 2.373301
                },
                {
                    path: '//placekitten.com/200/200?image=4',
                    img_lat: 47.504609, 
                    img_lng: 19.050323
                }
            ];










            async function initMap() {
              // store references to each marker here.
              let markers={};
            
              const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
              const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
              
              
              
              /* 
                  Conventional style callback functions 
                  allow access to the actual AdvancedMarkerElement 
                  via `this`
                  
                  markers are stored within `markers` object
                  so you can iterate through that Object to
                  perform various operations upon each marker
                  if required.
              */
              function clickhandler(e){
                document.querySelector('p#lat').textContent=Number(this.position.lat.toFixed(6));
                document.querySelector('p#lng').textContent=Number(this.position.lng.toFixed(6));
                document.querySelector('img#stage_img').src=this.content.querySelector('img.map-icon').src;
              }

              function draghandler(e){
                console.log( this, e.latLng )
                this.content.querySelector('[data-id="lat"]').textContent=Number(e.latLng.lat().toFixed(6));
                this.content.querySelector('[data-id="lng"]').textContent=Number(e.latLng.lng().toFixed(6));
              }
              
              
              
              
              
              // utility to generate suitable HTML content used within the AdvancedMarkerElement
              const createicon=( obj )=>{
                let div=document.createElement('div');
                    div.className='advmarker';
                    div.innerHTML=`
                        <h3>${obj.path.split('?').pop()}</h3>
                        <img class='map-icon' src='${obj.path}' />
                        <span data-id='lat'>${obj.img_lat}</span>
                        <span data-id='lng'>${obj.img_lng}</span>`;
                return div;
              };
              
              
              
              /* 
                utility to add a reasonable good id to each marker
                - allows easy access to each marker within global markers object
                - 
              */
              const createid=()=>window.URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [] ) ).split('/').pop();
              
              
              const addmarker=( obj, callbacks={} )=>{
                let mkr=new AdvancedMarkerElement({
                    map:map,
                    gmpDraggable:obj.draggable || true,
                    gmpClickable:obj.clickable || true,
                    position:{ 
                        'lat':obj.img_lat,
                        'lng':obj.img_lng 
                    },
                    content:createicon( obj )
                });
                
                /*
                    add data and custom propertiesy to the marker which 
                    allows access to them data within click handler.
                */
                mkr.data=obj;
                mkr.id=obj.id;
                
                
                if( callbacks && typeof( callbacks )=='object' ) {
                    Object.keys( callbacks ).forEach( type=>{
                        if( !~type.indexOf('gmp') )mkr.addListener( type, callbacks[ type ] );
                        else mkr.addEventListener( type, callbacks[ type ] );

                    });
                }
                
                return mkr;
              };
              
              
              
              const createMarkers=()=>{
                const callbacks={
                    'gmp-click':clickhandler,
                    'dragend':draghandler
                };
                
                images.forEach( obj => {
                    let id=createid();
                    let args=Object.assign( obj, {'id':id } );
                    let marker=addmarker( args, callbacks );
                    
                    markers[ id ]=marker;
                });
                return markers;
              };




              const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                mapId: "559497c6e95d32fc",
                zoom: 6,
                center: myLatLng,
                fullscreenControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                zoomControl: true
              });
              
              return createMarkers();
            }


            initMap()
                .then(console.log)
                .catch(console.warn)

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```